# If $R$ is transitive and $S$ is reflexive, Prove $(R\ ; S\ ;R)^2 \subseteq (R\ ;S)^3$

Tags: relations

$ R $ and $S$ are two relations.

Given $R$ is transitive and $S$ is reflexive

How can I Prove $(R\ ; S\ ;R)^2 \subseteq (R\ ;S)^3$

Comment: I tried expanding it but I am not sure how to move ahead.

Comment: Can you tell me what the notation $(R;S;R)$ and $(R;S)$ means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have, by associativity, that
$$ (R;S;R)^2 = R;S;R;R;S;R = R;S;R^2;S;R $$
Now, as $R$ is transitive, $R^2\subseteq R$, hence
$$ (R;S;R)^2 \subseteq R;S;R;S;R $$
As $S$ is reflexive $\operatorname{id}\subseteq S$, giving
$$ (R;S;R)^2 \subseteq R;S;R;S;R = R;S;R;S;R;\operatorname{id} \subseteq R;S;R;S;R;S = (R;S)^3 $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Comment: can you just explain that as $S$ is reflexive then why we consider $Id  \subseteq S$